# proper quoting of theorems

Tags: soft-question

Dear collegues, I am writing an overview paper for an academic journal, where I also need to state theorems proved by other authors. Usually I cite the source and then rephrase the theorem. However in a few cases rephrasing seems counterproductive and the optimal formulation was already given by the author. Is it OK to refer to the original author and then give say a 2 lines long theorem verbatim? Can this be considered as a ``weak" form of plagiarism?  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How could an attributed direct quotation be viewed as plagiarism?

Comment: In past I had a similar problem with my Ph.D. advisor - he wanted me to state his theorem in quoting marks. To me it seems over the top, but I would like to know general opinion.

Comment: Would not
http://academia.stackexchange.com/
be a better place for this question?...

Comment: I think that mathematical theorem is very special, formalized form of an academic text  for which different quoting rules may apply.   For that reason I prefer to ask here. 

Comment: If you really do want to quote a theorem verbatim, I agree that quotation marks would look strange.  Perhaps a more graceful solutoin would be to say: "The following theorem is taken verbatim from [99]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the style of your exposition, one possibility for distinguishing rephrased from verbatim results might be to say something along the lines of "In [reference], So-and-So proved a theorem that can be stated as follows: ..." on the one hand, and "In [reference], So-and-So stated and proved the following theorem: ..." on the other.

Comment: Golly that a quick acceptance!  Are you sure you don't want to wait to see what other people suggest?

Comment: Yes I would like to know answers by others. Does my acceptance mean that I do not get other answers?  I am new to MathOverflow. 

Comment: No, other people can still give answers, and I would hope they will.

Comment: @unknown: it's just that people are less likely to look at the question; it shows up on the main page as having an accepted answer and therefore as already being resolved in some sense. 

Comment: I don't think the second formulation makes it clear that you are quoting the theorem verbatim.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, it is not plagiarism to use someone else's exact words as long as you make it clear that they are that other person's words and not your own.  If you do this with a long piece of text, though, it might be copyright infringement, and there I don't think either Barry's suggestions or quotation marks would help.  I think avoiding plagiarism is solely your responsibility, but avoiding copyright infringement is something you and the eventual publisher of your paper should handle together.  (Maybe I should add that I consider plagiarism a serious moral issue; copyright is primarily a legal issue with, admittedly, some connections to morality.)

Comment: How much does the length of the theorem affect your answer? In particular, is a two-line quote (as the OP originally postulated) within an academic context likely to constitute copyright infringement?

Comment: Charles, I would expect a two-line quote to be well within the "fair use" that is allowed by copyright law, but I'm not a lawyer, so my expectations don't really count.  That's one reason why I suggested involving the publisher when copyright issues arise; presumably publishers have lawyers, whose guidance is worth something (unlike mine).  In general, I feel that common sense is usually a good guide for moral questions but not for legal ones.

Comment: I find that the opposite of common sense is usually a good guide for legal questions :)